# if and else with and

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

My first page is checkbox form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="1.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="count" value="count">count<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="search" value="search">search<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="order" value="order">order 
<input type="submit" value ="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then my next page is collecting the values using post and by using if conditions displaying the result

```
  <?php
    if(empty($_POST['count'])) { 
           $_POST['count']=''; 
        }
        else { 
            $a=$_POST['count']; 
        }
        if(empty($_POST['order'])) {
            $_POST['order']=''; 
        }
        else { 
            $b=$_POST['order']; 
        }
         if(empty($_POST['search'])) {
            $_POST['search']=''; 
        }
        else { 
            $c=$_POST['search']; 
        }

       if($_POST['count']=="count" && $_POST['search']=="search" && $_POST['order']=="order" )  {
          echo  "I have a count ,search and order" ;
       } 
        else if($_POST['order']=="order" && $_POST['count']=="count" && $_POST['search']!="search"  )  {
           echo "I have a order and count";
        }
        else if($_POST['search']=="search" && $_POST['count']=="count" && $_POST['order']!="order"  )  {
           echo "I have a search and count";
        }
         else if($_POST['search']=="search" && $_POST['order']=="order" && $_POST['count']!="count"  )  {
           echo "I have a search and order";
        }           
       else if($_POST['count']=="count" || $_POST['search']=="search" || $_POST['order']=="order"  ) {
          echo $_POST['count'];
          echo $_POST['search'];
          echo $_POST['order'];
       }
?>
```

I have a bike condition is working

I have a car condition is working

I have a car and bike is not working , I am new to this language so plz help

Comment: @Fred `else(condition)` surely won't work. `elseif` sounds more correct.

Comment: @Fred Why? I don't know of any language where you can put a condition to the `else`. `else` means "in all other cases".

Comment: @glglgl Ok, my bad. I was putting `else` inside an `()` where it should've been inside `{}`.

Comment: @user2657625 Why did you now change your question after it was resolved/answered? You should've posted that originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will newer reach the last `elseif` statement.  I would move the last else if -statement to top.

```
    <?
    if(empty($_POST['vehicle'])) { 
           $_POST['vehicle']=''; 
        }
        else { 
            $a=$_POST['vehicle']; 
        }
        if(empty($_POST['vehicle1'])) {
            $_POST['vehicle1']=''; 
        }
        else { 
            $b=$_POST['vehicle1']; 
        }
       if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike" && $_POST['vehicle1']=="Car")  {
          echo  "I have a car and bike" ;
       } 
        else if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike") {
           echo "I have a bike";
        }       
       else if($_POST['vehicle1']=="Car") {
          echo  "I have a car" ;
       }
?>
```

Comment: you solve my problem but if i have more than 3 checkbox then what i do

Comment: that's another question. Depends on how many checkboxes and what kind of html form do you have.

Comment: if i have 4 checkbox then , should i edit my form to get my answer

Answer (score 3):

You try:

```
...
if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike" && $_POST['vehicle1']=="Car")  {
       echo  "I have a car and bike" ;
} else if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike") {
        echo "I have a bike";
} else if($_POST['vehicle1']=="Car") {
       echo  "I have a car" ;
}
```

"A car and bike" is not working because condition 1 is true => condition 2 and 3 not be tested again.

IF - Else if: If condition 1 is false then condition 2 is check, then if condition 2 false then condition 3 is check.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `else` and try like

```
<?php

if ($_POST['vehicle'] == "Bike" && $_POST['vehicle1'] == "Car")  {
   echo "I have a car and bike" ;
} else if ($_POST['vehicle'] == "Bike") {
    echo "I have a bike";
} else if ($_POST['vehicle1'] == "Car") {
   echo "I have a car" ;
}

?>
```

Comment: i am getting the result like this I have a bikeI have a car and bike –

Comment: Going to +1, your is by far better and uses less code to do the job.

Comment: @Gautam3164 Had the OP not changed his question "after" he accepted another answer, am sure you would've came up with a different answer, am I correct? The OP did not fair well at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(empty($_POST['vehicle'])) { 
       $_POST['vehicle']=''; 
    }
    else { 
        $a=$_POST['vehicle']; 
    }
    if(empty($_POST['vehicle1'])) {
        $_POST['vehicle1']=''; 
    }
    else { 
        $b=$_POST['vehicle1']; 
    }
    if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike" && $_POST['vehicle1']!="Car") {
       echo "I have a bike";
    }       
   elseif($_POST['vehicle1']=="Car" && $_POST['vehicle']!="Bike") {
      echo  "I have a car" ;
   }
   if($_POST['vehicle']=="Bike" && $_POST['vehicle1']=="Car")  {
      echo  "I have a car and bike" ;
   }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eg\1.php on line 21

Comment: error problem is solved but i am getting the result like this **I have a bikeI have a car and bike**

Comment: Check the updated answer @user2657625.I think that will be your requirment

Comment: give me some reputation